# Open sublime text editor into eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, sublimetext

Is there a way to open the Sublime Text Editor into Eclipse to edit HTML, JavaScript and CSS?

The idea is to use only the Text Editor without project explorer.

If this isn't possible, is there a plugin that does what I said?

Comment: Any luck with a solution? I got vim running inside eclipse as an editor via "vimplugin", but no luck with sublime so far for me :(
I would really like something like you describe, because I find eclipse's JavaScript-editor way too simple (even nodeclipse's and aptana's).

Comment: I too find `Sublime Text` really far more convenient and powerful than built-in editors in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I would have just left this as a comment but I can't. First off, why is using the project explorer a problem?

Next, I know with Sublime Text 2 & 3 you have the ability to view/edit a file in two places simultaneously, just go `File > New View into File`. In Eclipse you can go `Window > New Window`. Alternatively you can import a project/file into eclipse or sublime. Either of these will bring in the project explorer (unless you import one file or something).

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer, the project explorer of sublime isn't a problem... but my idea is to switch the standard text editor of Eclipse with the text editor of Sublime. If is possible could be a good way open, a window, into Eclipse (like a web iFrame) the text editor of Sublime so I don't need the project explorer of Sublime.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [Subclim](https://github.com/JulianEberius/Subclim) + [Eclim](http://eclim.org/).

I had to open the files via "Project Explorer -> Open With -> External -> sublime" to get the files refreshed right away (e.g. for a running webapp). But other from that, it's quite nice.

Comment: Sadly, "Subclim + Eclim" seems to be the other way around, it integrates Eclipse-Features into sublime.